# ag Grid change cell color on Cell Value Change

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to change cell color when cell old value != cell new value in a grid.

I've tried:

```
if (e.oldValue === e.newValue)    {   
    e.colDef.cellStyle = function(e) {return { backgroundColor: 'green' };
}
```

But when save is hit or data is reloaded, it changes the column color to green.

Comment: it is unclear from this snippet. you probably need to use api.refreshCells()

Comment: `onCellValueChanged = e => {   
   console.log(e); // access the entire event object  
   e.data.modified = true;
   if (e.oldValue === e.newValue)
  {
    e.colDef.cellStyle = function(e) {
      return { backgroundColor: 'green' };
    };
  } 
 }`

I need to change the color of cell which has changed value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ag-grid does not have a built in feature to highlight edited cells. you can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Dynamically updating cell Style -

   ```
   onCellValueChanged(params) {
     if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
         var column = params.column.colDef.field;
               params.column.colDef.cellStyle = { 'background-color': 'cyan' };
               params.api.refreshCells({
                   force: true,
                   columns: [column],
                   rowNodes: [params.node]
           });
     }}
   ```
2. Using a combination of `cellClassRules`, an edit flag and `onCellValueChanged` -

   - Define a css class for edited cell.
     `.green-bg {background-color: olivedrab;}`
   - Define cellClassRules for the column which applies style based on flag you update on edit.
     `cellClassRules: {
     'green-bg': (params) => { return params.data.isEdited}
     }`
   - Then you set the flag in your `onCellValueChanged` something like this -

```
onCellValueChanged(params) {
          if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
             params.data.isEdited = true; // set the flag
          }
          params.api.refreshCells(); //causes styles to be reapplied based on cellClassRules
        }
```

Comment: I implemented first way and it is working fine without change the pagination. But if i change the pagination, Its showing whole column in the highlighted color. How can i fix this bug ?

Comment: If i will go with second option, it is not working with multiple columns edit. If i edit one column cell.. it is highlighting other columns as well.

Comment: So that all the columns don't change their color, instead of doing `params.data.isEdited = true` do like this `params.data.isEdited = params.colDef.field`. And in cellClassRules do, `'green-bg': (params) => { return params.data.isEdited === params.colDef.field}`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

@Coding Professor.
The correct usage for way 1 is as follows:

```
if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
        params.colDef.cellStyle = (p) =>
            p.rowIndex.toString() === params.node.id ? {'background-color': 'red'} : "";

        params.api.refreshCells({
            force: true,
            columns: [params.column.getId()],
            rowNodes: [params.node]
        });
    }
```

With way 2, I think this is incorrect way. Especially when you use columnGroupShow: 'open'

Comment: Thanks. This answer is working fine. Just need to change `{'background-color': 'red'} : ""` to `{'background-color': 'red'} : {}`. Otherwise, it may throw an error. The accepted answer does not work properly now, it changes whole column color instead of edited cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement it with a custom cellRenderer
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#reference-ICellRendererParams