# refresh row after cell value change in ag-grid javascript

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have searched for a long time for this and I'm sure I must have missed something because it is such a basic ask.

I define the formats in my grid through the `cellClass` field in `defaultColDef`:

```js
cellClass: (params) => {
    if (params.data.signal_days === 1 && params.data.trade_type !== "taken"  ) {
        return "signals-blotter-cell-new";
    } else if (params.data.trade_type === "taken"  ) {
        return "signals-blotter-cell-taken";
    }
}
```

Depending on the value of the `signal_days` and `trade_type` columns, different css classes get applied.

I also have a `onCellValueChanged` event listener defined as such :

```js
onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
    if (event.column.colId === "trade_type") {
    }
}
```

How can I refresh the cells **for the whole row** where the modification happened so that my css classes are properly applied ? I would need to refresh when the value of the `trade_type` column changes from anything to "taken". [Some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222534/ag-grid-change-cell-color-on-cell-value-change) use that same mechanism for a single cell which does not help me in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ag Grid change cell color on Cell Value Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222534/ag-grid-change-cell-color-on-cell-value-change)

Comment: It doesn't because it doesn't change the style on the row. only on the specific cell (which I already do with my existing code) I need the refresh to happen on the whole row.

Comment: well the idea is the same, you need to call params.api.refreshCells() and pass the rowNode you want to refresh

Comment: Yes I do not know how to get the  rowNode from the event object

Comment: and the refresh needs to happen within onCellValueChanged : do I have access to params there ? Thought event was the only object available.

Comment: added an answer, basically your event = params, better to name it as params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like -

```
onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
    if (event.column.colId === "trade_type") {
       event.api.refreshCells({
                    force: true,
                    rowNodes: [event.node] // pass rowNode that was edited
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you. Thought the event.node was the cell and not the row.

Comment: Glad it helped. That was the reason I pointed out it is similar to the linked question

Comment: Any guess about how can it be done for complete grid data. Like what I want is to change the data of other rows too when a given cell value is changed. This is only updating the row with index in which cell has been updated.